# Pandas iterate over DataFrame row pairs

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

How can I iterate over pairs of rows of a Pandas DataFrame?

For example:

```
content = [(1,2,[1,3]),(3,4,[2,4]),(5,6,[6,9]),(7,8,[9,10])]
df = pd.DataFrame( content, columns=["a","b","interval"])
print df
```

output:

```
   a  b interval
0  1  2   [1, 3]
1  3  4   [2, 4]
2  5  6   [6, 9]
3  7  8  [9, 10]
```

Now I would like to do something like

```
for (indx1,row1), (indx2,row2) in df.?
    print "row1:\n", row1
    print "row2:\n", row2
    print "\n"
```

which should output

```
row1:
a    1
b    2
interval    [1,3]
Name: 0, dtype: int64
row2:
a    3
b    4
interval    [2,4]
Name: 1, dtype: int64

row1:
a    3
b    4
interval    [2,4]
Name: 1, dtype: int64
row2:
a    5
b    6
interval    [6,9]
Name: 2, dtype: int64

row1:
a    5
b    6
interval    [6,9]
Name: 2, dtype: int64
row2:
a    7
b    8
interval    [9,10]
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

Is there a builtin way to achieve this?
I looked at df.groupby(df.index // 2) and df.itertuples but none of these methods seems to do what I want.

**Edit:**
The overall goal is to get a list of bools indicating whether the intervals in column "interval" overlap. In the above example the list would be

```
overlaps = [True, False, False]
```

So one bool for each pair.

Comment: You can try shift, which essentially returns a dataframe of "the next rows".

Comment: How would one then combine df and df.shift(1)?

Comment: Why do you want to loop? Post your greater problem.. you probably dont need the looping

Comment: One column of the dataframe contains an interval in each row and I want to check if the intervals overlap pairwise.

Comment: @Lxndr your problem has been asked plenty of times actually (the interval problem). Definetly dont need a loop to do this. Will get very slow as your data frame size increases

Comment: Do you have a link? I'm not really sure what to search for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function on pairs of rows in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711358/apply-function-on-pairs-of-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the loop `for`, using `zip` and `iterrows` could be a way

```
for (indx1,row1),(indx2,row2) in zip(df[:-1].iterrows(),df[1:].iterrows()):
    print "row1:\n", row1
    print "row2:\n", row2
    print "\n"
```

To access the next row at the same time, start the second iterrow one row after with `df[1:].iterrows()`. and you get the output the way you want.

```
row1:
a    1
b    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
row2:
a    3
b    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64


row1:
a    3
b    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
row2:
a    5
b    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64


row1:
a    5
b    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64
row2:
a    7
b    8
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

But as said @RafaelC, doing `for` loop might not be the best method for your general problem.

Answer (score 15):

shift the dataframe & concat it back to the original using `axis=1` so that each interval & the next interval are in the same row

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).add_prefix('next_')], axis=1)
df_merged
#Out:
   a  b interval     next_a     next_b    next_interval
0  1  2   [1, 3]        3.0        4.0           [2, 4]
1  3  4   [2, 4]        5.0        6.0           [6, 9]
2  5  6   [6, 9]        7.0        8.0          [9, 10]
3  7  8  [9, 10]        NaN        NaN              NaN
```

define an intersects function that works with your lists representation & apply on the merged data frame ignoring the last row where the `shifted_interval` is null

```
def intersects(left, right):
    return left[1] > right[0]

df_merged[:-1].apply(lambda x: intersects(x.interval, x.next_interval), axis=1)
#Out:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is awesome! I will leave @Ben.T 's answer as the accepted though since it better answers my original question. I will use this for my problem though!

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you've shown use:

```
for row in df.index[:-1]:
    print 'row 1:'
    print df.iloc[row].squeeze()
    print 'row 2:'
    print df.iloc[row+1].squeeze()
    print
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more 'pythonic' solution. This to me looks like 
for i in xrange(len(iterable)):
  print iterable[i]

Comment: @Lxndr Your request is to `print` in certain way, and this approach uses `pandas` specific methods to generate desired output

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) indexing.

Exmaple:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):                        
    idx1,idx2=i,i+1                         
    row1,row2=df.iloc[idx1],df.iloc[idx2]   
    print(row1)                             
    print(row2)                             
    print()
```

Comment: This has the same problem as @zipa 's answer