# Apply function on pairs of rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a newbie to pandas dataframe, and I wanted to apply a function taking couple of rows in the same column. Like when you apply the function diff(), but i want to calculate the distance between text. so i defined a function which measure the distance, and i tried to use apply but i don't know how can i pick couple of rows. Below i show an example that i'have tried to do and what i expected:

```
def my_measure_function(x,y):
   return some_distance_calculus(x,y)

>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame({"text": ['hello','hella','hel'], "B": [3,4,4]})
>>> df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda x, y: my_measure_function(x, y), axis=0)
```

but it doesn't work.
What i want to obtain is:

```
>>> df
      text  B  dist
0    hello  3    0
1    hella  4    1
2    hel    4    2
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide me.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to avoid [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), as [performance may suffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c/52674448#52674448). Instead, you can use `map` with [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['dist'] = list(map(my_measure_function, df['text'], df['text'].shift()))
```

Or via a list comprehension:

```
zipper = zip(df['text'], df['text'].shift())
df['dist'] = [my_measure_function(val1, val2) for val1, val2 in zipper]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but i need to compare rows from the same column, in this case "text" column. I need to calculate the distance between 'hella' vs 'hello' and 'hel' vs 'hella' and put the result in a new columm.

Comment: @M.Moresi, Ah, I see, I've added a couple of options there.

Comment: @Wen, Yep, I've recently had bad experience with `apply` though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c/52674448#52674448) which is why I'm avoiding!

Comment: @jpp  since he asking the apply function - that is why I am using the `apply  `

Comment: I had to wait a minute to get my vote back, but yours definitely deserves +1 as the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

For `diff`, which is `s-s.shift()`, so in your function you can do

```
df['shifttext']=df.text.shift()
df.apply(lambda x : my_measure_function(x['text'],x['shifttext']))
```