# Pandas iterate over three rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, row

According to these question [Pandas iterate over DataFrame row pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443725/pandas-iterate-over-dataframe-row-pairs)

I want to iterate over three rows like question above, but I find it difficult.

```py
for (indx1,row1),(indx2,row2) in zip(df[:-1].iterrows(),df[1:].iterrows()):
    print "row1:\n", row1
    print "row2:\n", row2
    print "\n"
```

These are the code in the solution for iterating two rows, and I want to modify these code so it could iterate three rows.

I am trying `df.index//3` or `df[::3]` but it's not what I want.
Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (indx1,row1),(indx2,row2),(indx3,row3) in zip(
    df[:-2].iterrows(),df[1:-1].iterrows(),df[2:].iterrows()):

    print "row1:\n", row1
    print "row2:\n", row2
    print "row3:\n", row3
    print "\n"
```

Is this what you're looking for? Btw, it's about time to say goodbye to Python2...

Comment: and what if I only want to display per three rows in the last two rows? thank you for advice, I actually use Python3

Comment: I don't understand, what you're trying to say here. Can you try again? Maybe I can help then.

Comment: I mean, I want to iterate over three rows in only two columns, then in the function of iteration, I do linear regression in that three rows. So, iterate over three rows, do linear regression, iterate over three rows, do linear regression, so on.

Comment: You just have to iterate over the two columns then. So df[:-2] becomes df.iloc[:-2,:2] if you want only the first two columns, and so on. But that means that you just have 6 values per iteration and that's probably not enough for whatever you're trying to do with a regression. Don't get me wrong, but I get the feeling that you'd be better of by working through a pandas intro tutorial and then figure it out. Because this stuff here is really basic.