# Iterating in pairs with DataFrame when total number of rows is odd

Tags: python, dataframe

As I work with `multiprocessing` and I have a limit of two API calls at a time, so I need to iterate with a maximum of two lines at a time.

The problem is that sometimes the `DataFrame` doesn't have the total of even lines, so to work with total odd lines I created this model:

```
for_iterate = # DataFrame

if (len(for_iterate.index) % 2) == 0:
    df_a = for_iterate.iloc[::2]
    df_b = for_iterate.iloc[1::2]
    df_c = 'off'
else:
    for_iterate_odd = for_iterate.iloc[:-1]
    df_a = for_iterate_odd.iloc[::2]
    df_b = for_iterate_odd.iloc[1::2]
    df_c = for_iterate.iloc[-1:]

final_list = []
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:

    for (_, example_dataframe_a), (_, example_dataframe_b) in zip(df_a.iterrows(), df_b.iterrows()):
        res_1 = pool.apply_async(add_hour, args=(example_dataframe_a,))
        res_2 = pool.apply_async(add_hour, args=(example_dataframe_b,))
        final_list.extend([res_1.get(), res_2.get()])
    if df_c != 'off':
        final_list.append(pool.apply_async(add_hour, args=(df_c,)).get())
```

As you can see, when the total number of lines is not even, I use a separate object that collects only the last line of the `DataFrame` and make a separate `multiprocessing` to it.

Is there a smarter method of getting around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)? I imagine this could be restructured with a pool to run with the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

result_storage = pd.Series()
async def add_hour(ix, row):
    global result_storage
    ...
    result_storage[ix] = result

for_iterate = ...

with Pool(processes=2) as p:
    p.map(add_hour, for_iterate.iterrows())
```

EDIT: added global variable that is edited within the add_hour function

Comment: Hello friend, I would like to thank you in advance and let you know that I had forgotten to explain that I will use the values that ```return``` on ```add_hour``` to append it to a list, in case you want to analyze your answer to see if you think it is important to change something to fit the question . Sorry for editing the question, but I thought it was important to add the details!

Comment: That's on me! I missed that key piece of the code. I updated the code to hopefully result in the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the code in `add_hour`, you could just use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and short-circuit the function to return nothing if `None` gets passed in. If not, you could just make a wrapper that checks for `None` and calls `add_hour` otherwise.